# Assuming conditions for f(x,y) and g(x,y), Evaluate the limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Given:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (2,5)} f(x,y) = 3$$
and
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (2,5)} g(x,y) = 6$$

Evaluate or show that limit doesn't exist:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (2,5)} \frac{f(x,y)}{f(x,y) + g(x,y)}$$

To my limited understanding from reading text, I am assuming that since we are already given the limits of both f(x,y) and g(x,y) that we are just plugging in the values to get: 3/9 which evaluates to 1/3. Is it as simple as this or am I completely off? I appreciate any and all information and I hope this questions is better formatted than my previous :)

Comment: As simple as that..but it is based on an important theorem: arithmetic of limits. Just as with one-variable functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track! It's better to note what you're doing in terms of the rules of limits though. Like @DonAntonio said,

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (x_1,y_1)} \frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)} = \frac{\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_1,y_1)} f(x,y)}{\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_1,y_1)} g(x,y)} $$

And,

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (x_1,y_1)} f(x,y) + g(x,y) = \lim_{(x,y) \to (x_1,y_1)} f(x,y) + \lim_{(x,y) \to (x_1,y_1)} g(x,y) $$

Comment: Here you are abstracting out each step it seems, thank you for this